# How to create taxonomy archive page correctly?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

There is the custom post type called 'book' and custom taxonomy 'book-categories'for it.
On the main page I have a block, which has to open links to terms of that taxonomy.

```
<div class="row book-categories">  
 <?php    // your taxonomy name
$tax = 'book-categories';

// get the terms of taxonomy
$terms = get_terms( $tax, [
  'hide_empty' => false, // do not hide empty terms
]);

// loop through all terms
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
  // if no entries attached to the term
  if( 0 == $term->count )
    // display only the term name
    echo '<h4>' . $term->name . '</h4>';
  // if term has more than 0 entries
  elseif( $term->count > 0 )
    // display link to the term archive
    echo '<h4><a href="'. get_term_link( $term ) .'">'. $term->name .'</a></h4>';
}?>                
</div>
```

I created the file taxonomy-book-categories.php in the root of the theme. I re-saved permalinks, but when I click to any link, it opens like example.com/book-categories/loremipsum/ and shows the template of taxonomy.php, not my test-file taxonomy-book-categories.php content.
The post type was created before me

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_group_post_type' );
   function register_group_post_type() {       
  register_post_type('book', array(
    'label'               => 'book',
    'labels'              => array(
      'name'          => 'Livre',
      'singular_name' => 'Livre',
      'menu_name'     => 'Livre',
      'all_items'     => 'All Livre',
      'add_new'       => 'Add Livre',
      'add_new_item'  => 'Add new Livre',
      'edit'          => 'Edit',
      'edit_item'     => 'Edit Livre',
      'new_item'      => 'New Livre',
    ),
    'description'         => 'Livre',
    'public'              => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_rest'        => true,
    'rest_base'           => '',
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'map_meta_cap'        => true,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-format-image',
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'rewrite'             => false,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'thumbnail','editor'),
  ) );  
}
```

The taxonomy was created by me

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_subjects_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );    
function create_subjects_hierarchical_taxonomy() {    
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Book Categories ', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Book Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Book Category' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Book Categories' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Book Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Book Category:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Book Category' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Book Category' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Book Category' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Book Category Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Book Categories' ),  );    
  
// Now register the taxonomy
  register_taxonomy('book-categories',array('book'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'book-categories' ),
  ));  
}
```

What's wrong and how can I get to my taxonomy template from row book-categories div on the main page?(no, I don't use 'custom post types and custom taxonomy plugins' and don't plan to - need to figure out where I do mistakes in a code)

Answer (score 0):

You might try experimenting with the following...

1. Adding `'public' => true` to the array of options in `register_taxonomy`
2. Removing `'hierarchical'` from the array of options in `register_taxonomy`
3. Removing `'rewrite'` from the array of options in `register_taxonomy` (you probably don't need this as you haven't changed the slug).

Worth saving the Permalinks settings again after.